# inheritance example from typescript manual

Tags: class, oop, object, inheritance, typescript1.4

Reading example from [typescript manual](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes-inheritance):

```
class Animal {
    name:string;
    constructor(theName: string) { this.name = theName; }
    move(meters: number = 0) {
        alert(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(meters = 5) {
        alert("Slithering...");
        super.move(meters);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(meters = 45) {
        alert("Galloping...");
        super.move(meters);
    }
}

var sam = new Snake("Sammy the Python");
var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");

sam.move();
tom.move(34);
```

The question is about the line `var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");`:

- As I understand `tom` is an `Animal` with properties of a `Horse`. Is that right?
- What is the point to make it this way? Not to declare as `var tom: Horse = ...`?
- Having just one version to give him a chance to degrade/change/evolve to a `Snake` or any other `Animal`. Am I right?
- ...or maybe it is just a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example above, `Animal` is a **superclass** (also called *base class* or *parent class*) of both `Horse` and `Snake`. Correspondingly, `Horse` and `Snake` are **subclasses** (*derived classes*) of `Animal`.

When you declare the subclasses:

```
class Snake extends Animal
...
class Horse extends Animal
```

You're telling the compiler that any every `Snake` and every `Horse` is in fact, an `Animal` as well. This makes `Animal` the broader category in the "world" of the program. `Snake` and `Horse` will **inherit** the properties of `Animal`, but they can change them (and/or add a few of their own) to be more *specialized*.

- `tom`'s declaration tells the compiler that the variable will accept any `Animal`. As we saw earlier, a `Horse` is an `Animal`, so the compiler lets it pass.
- Hence, they're illustrating the fact that whenever a member of the superclass is expected in any expression, one member of any of its subclasses is acceptable. This is called **covariance**.
- In the most literal sense, there is no evolving or devolving. The line

  `tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");`

  first causes a new `Horse` object to be created. The object is then assigned to the variable `tom`, but this assignment does *not* change the properties of the object. If you ran the example, you'd see that the call `horse.move()` actually calls the `Horse` version of the method `move`, which would report that "Tommy the Palomino moved 45m".

  The only discernible side effect of assigning a `Horse` to an `Animal` is that the variable, being of the most general type, wouldn't know of any specialized properties of `Horse`. It only knows what all `Animal`s have in common. Let's say `Horse` was declared like this:

  ```
  class Horse extends Animal {
      constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
      move(meters = 45) {
          //...
      }
      swat_fly() { /* ... */ }
  }
  ```

  You wouldn't be able to call `tom.swat_fly()`. If you wanted to, you either need to typecast `tom` (like this: `(<Horse>tom).swat_fly()`) or declare it as a `Horse` instead of as an `Animal`. But I reiterate: the object's properties are not changed to the superclass's.
- So no, it's not a typo :)